# Homekit notification using homebridge

Tags: home-automation

I'm using homebridge on my raspberry pi 3b to add smart home products to my home app. But how can I create a homekit notification using homekit? I want to start a notification at 15 o'clock every day.

Comment: what research have you done? ... what have you tried? ... what problem did you encounter?

Comment: @jsotola I don‘t found anything